# jQuery: how do I have two date pickers?

Tags: jquery

On my site, I want to have a date range thing, so I figured I'd use two date pickers from 
http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

currently, both date pickers edit the same field... which makes me sad.

```
$j(function() {
    $j(".date-range-start .date-picker input").datepicker({
        //showOtherMonths: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showAnim: 'fadeIn',
        showOn: 'button'
    });
    $j(".date-range-end .date-picker input").datepicker({
        //showOtherMonths: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showAnim: 'fadeIn',
        showOn: 'button'
    });
});
```

i figured since I have two different selectors I'd be able to change two different fields, right?

well... apparently it hates me.

```
<div class="date-range-picker">
            <div class="date-range-start">
                <div class="date-picker">
                    <input id="classinput-field" name="classinput-field" type="text" class="hasDatepicker"><button type="button" class="ui-datepicker-trigger">...</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="date-range-end">
                <div class="date-picker">
                    <input id="classinput-field" name="classinput-field" type="text" class="hasDatepicker"><button type="button" class="ui-datepicker-trigger">...</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: As a quick test, what happens if you give each input an "id" and use that as the selector?

Comment: switching to ids did it. (once I made them unique)

Comment: Your two IDs of the input elements are the same. That's a no-no. Also, you seem to be suffering from a chronic case of class-itis.

Comment: yeah, I was using ruby to generate the input boxes, and I did it wrong =)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Give them two separate ID's.

```
$("#id1").datepicker();
$("#id2").datepicker();
```

Comment: That was my idea too. You beat me by five seconds. :)

Comment: Plus one for using id's. It is interesting (maybe a bug) that id's are needed to handle multiple datepickers. I had specific selectors for two datepickers, but it would only work when I used explicit #ids on each.